# Documentation/explanation of Android Windowing System/WindowManagerService class

Tags: android

Please help me with finding sufficient documentation/explaination of **Android** WindowManagerService class?
or in general Android Windowing System.

Answer (score 0):

Found this, explains windows and call stacks well: http://www.worlduc.com/UploadFiles/BlogFile/359%5C10813941%5Candroid%20graphics%20architecture.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Find this presentation, may help you.

http://people.debian.org.tw/~olv/surfaceflinger/surfaceflinger.pdf